# Parse a JSON object from a string that contains more than just the JSON object

Tags: c#, json.net

I receive a response from an API call and handle the response with three cases.

- Failure
- Failed because the actions were already performed
- Success

I handle the case with "Failed due to previous completed actions" as a success.

The response with this case returns a string that I need to parse a JSON object from is as such

```
Failed ID is already closed  {"ID":"0",system":"","user":"","secondaryID":"","date":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","currency":"USD"}
```

What is the best way to retrieve the JSON object from the given API response? I have attempted to use the below line of code to parse the object from the given 'response' string. The number of the proceeding characters to the JSON object will be variable in length.

```
AlreadyCompleteModel jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlreadyCompleteModel>(response);
```

I appreciate a suggestion for a solution that will provide a string that can be parsed with the below line of code

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlreadyCompleteModel>(response);
```

Comment: `with the below line of code` that's not possible. No JSON serializer can parse this. You'll have to find the part of the string that's valid JSON, extract it and parse it. If the JSON part is always at the end you can search for the first occurrence of `{` or `[`, eg `var json=response.SubString(0,response.IndexOf('}'));`

Comment: If the response is always 2 lines, you can split on newline and deserialize the second line.

Comment: Or look for the first `{` or `[`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a solution that works

```
string jsonString = response.Substring(response.IndexOf("{"));
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlreadyCompleteModel>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

The suggested solution to look for `{` or `[` is a bit fragile. It could still extract a substring at the end of the string which is not part of the json. You might consider to use Regex instead:

```
static string pattern = @"((\[[^\}]{3,})?\{s*[^\}\{]{3,}?:.*\}([^\{]+\])?)";
static readonly Regex jsonRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

public static void Main()
{

    string[] inputs = [
        @"Failed ID is already closed  {""ID"":""0"",system"":"""",""user"":"""",""secondaryID"":"""",""date"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""currency"":""USD""}",
        @"Failed ID is already closed  {""ID"":""0"",system"":"""",""user"":"""",""secondaryID"":"""",""date"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""currency"":""USD""", //missing }
        @"Failed ID is already closed  {""ID"":""0"",system"":"""",""user"":"""",""secondaryID"":"""",""date"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""currency"":""USD""} extra", //with extra
    ];

    foreach(var input in inputs)
    {
        var ismatch = jsonRegex.IsMatch(input);
        Console.WriteLine($"{input}: {ismatch}");
    }
}
```

Please bear in mind that this regex is not fully-fletched for any json. It means you can receive false positives as well. For example:

```
@"Failed ID is already closed  {""ID"":""0"",system"":"""",""user"":"""",""secondaryID"":"""",""date"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""currency"":""USD""}}", //double }
@"Failed ID is already closed  {""ID"":""0"",system"":"""",""user"":"""",""secondaryID"":"""",""date"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""currency"":""USD""]", //] instead of }
etc.
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VsVkLJ)

---

Depending on your requirements, you might need to use more complex regex like [this](https://regex101.com/library/tA9pM8)